# Where can I find a brief description of the various types of web services?

Tags: web-services

SOAP, ASMX, WCF, REST, others... where can I find a reference for the various web service types and the situations they are best suited? Any diagrams that show show all the components are related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Wikipedia article for a list of webservices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications). That should get you started in the right direction. If you wish to go into further detail, the [paper of Tim Berners Lee hosted on W3C](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/WebServices.html) might give you some more input.